# DataFrameWriter.csv() trimming all fields in The Dataset<Row> while writing to CSV file

Tags: apache-spark

While writing the `Dataset<Row>` into csv file using `DataFrameWriter` csv method in spark 2.1 , it is trimming all the String fields by default.
For example, for the columns:

```
"    0"," Shop "," CA"
```

It is writing as:

```
"0","Shop","CA"
```

in the csv file.

I have used the options :

```
dataFrame.write()
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "false")
  .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd")
  .option("sep", ",")
  .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "false")
  .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace","false")                 
  .option("escape", "\"")
  .option("quoteALL","true")
  .save(path);
```

But still it is trimming the fields.
I want the fields to be untrimmed.
Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you have to RTFSC = "read the f... **source code**".

I found the source for `DataFrameWriter` in branch 2.1 here:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala

And the comments state that...

> You can set the following CSV-specific option(s) for **writing** CSV
>   files
>  `sep` ... `quote` ... `escape` ... `escapeQuotes` ...
>   `quoteAll` ... `header` ... `nullValue` ... `compression` ...
>   `dateFormat` ... `timestampFormat`

That's why your settings for `ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace` and `ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace` are ignored -- they apply only when **reading** a CSV file, via [`DataFrameReader`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala).

---

At this point, you have to experiment with **quotes**.
*[edit]* <strike>Your example already shows quotes everywhere, although you don't force `quoteAll` which is false by default. Really puzzling.</strike>

My suggestion: transform the columns that you want to keep untrimmed by adding *explicitly* quotes characters around the values, then save the result as CSV *without automatic quoting*.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add quoteALL  in code. I am already using it , and I need it in all fields. I have edited the code in the questions. In spark 1.6 , the same code is not trimming the fields,which is trimming here. Is there any way to avoid the trimming of each string fields?

Comment: I have no clue. Does the trimming occur only with CSV, or also with JSON _(readable with a text editor)_ or Parquet _(would require another Spark command to read it back)_?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't there be another method be called at the end (like `text(path)` or `save(path)`?

Are the other options working? A wild guess is that is has something to do with ordering.

Comment: text(path) is only applicable for a single column of type string, and I have more than one column. I am using save(path) only: I forgot to add that part in my question. My code part is :
    dataFrame.write()
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "false")
  .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd")
  .option("sep", ",")
  .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "false")
  .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace","false")                 
  .option("escape", "\"")
   .option("quoteALL","true").save(path);